# Converting code to a list comprehension

Tags: python

I wrote a bit of code to iterate over a list to see if a line contained one or more keywords:

```
STRINGS_TO_MATCH = [ "Foo",
                     "Bar",
                     "Oggle" ]

for string in STRINGS_TO_MATCH
    if string in line:
        val_from_line = line.split(' ')[-1]
```

Does anyone happen to know if there is a way to make this more readable? Would a list comprehension be a better fit here?

Comment: what is `line`?

Comment: Also, is `val_from_line` supposed to be a list?

Comment: Each input file has 100s of random lines. line contains each line as I'm iterating over the file. val_from_line would contain a specific field from the file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to remember here is that *comprehensions are expressions*, whose purpose is to create a value - list comprehensions create lists, dict comprehensions create dicts, and set comprehensions create sets. They are unlikely to help in this case, because you aren't creating any such object.

Your code sample is incomplete, because it doesn't *do* anything with the `val_from_line` values that it extracts.  I am presuming that you want to extract the last "word" from a `line` which contains any of the strings in `STRINGS_TO_MATCH`, but it's difficult to work with such incomplete information so this answer might, for all I know, be totally useless.

Assuming I'm correct, the easiest way to find out if `line` contains any of the `STRINGS_TO_MATCH` is to use the expression

```
any(s in line for s in STRINGS_TO_MATCH)
```

This uses a so-called *generator expression*, which is similar to a list comprehension - the interpreter can iterate over it to produce a sequence of values - but it doesn't go as far as creating a list of the values, it just creates them as the client code (in this case the `any` built-in function) requests them. So I might rewrite your code as

```
if any(s in line for s in STRINGS_TO_MATCH):
    val_from_line = line.split(' ')[-1]
```

I'll leave you to decide what you actually want to do after that, with the warning note that after this code executes `val_from_line` may or may not exist (depending on whether or not the condition was true), which is never an entirely comfortable situation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!